# Limiting the number of hits in a Biopython NCBIWWW Search

Tags: python, biopython, ncbi

I'm working on trying to automate some BLAST searches. I need to pick up only the top three results from the BLAST results, however the parameter `hitlist_size` doesn't seem to be limiting my searches to only three results. No matter what size I specify I still end up getting > 3 hits for most samples (in others I get three, although I'm not sure if this is simply coincidence) . Does anyone have any insight to this?

```
import Bio
from Bio import SeqIO
from Bio.Blast import NCBIWWW
from Bio.Blast import NCBIXML
fasta_string = open("FASTA_Files/48_50.fasta").read()
result_handle = NCBIWWW.qblast("blastn", "nt", fasta_string,hitlist_size=3)
    with open("XML_Files/48_50.xml", "w") as save_to:
        save_to.write(result_handle.read())
        result_handle.close()
```

The following FASTA sequence produces the expected number of hits for `46` but exceeds the expected number of hits for `47`:

```
>46
NNNNNNNNNNGNNNNNNTGCAGTCGNANNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNAGCTTGCTGCTTCGCTGACGAGTGGCGGACGGGTGA
GTAATGTCTGGGAAACTGCCTGATGGAGGGGGATAACTACTGGAAACGGTGGCTAATACCGCATAACGTCGCAAGACCAA
AGAGGGGGACCTTCGGGCCTCTTGCCATCAGATGTGCCCAGATGGGATTAGCTTGTTGGTGAGGTAACGGCTCACCAAGG
CGACGATCCCTAGCTGGTCTGAGAGGATGACCAGCCACACTGGAACTGAGACACGGTCCAGACTCCTACGGGAGGCAGCA
GTGGGGAATATTGCACAATGGGCGCAAGCCTGATGCAGCCATGCCGCGTGTATGAAGAAGGCCTTCGGGTTGTAAAGTAC
TTTCAGCGGGGAGGAAGGNGTTGTGGTTAATAACCGCAGCAATTGACGTTACCCGCANAANAAGCACCGGCTAACTCCGT
GCCAGCAGCCGCGGTAATACGGAGGGTGCANGCGTTAATCGNAATTACTGGNCGTAAAGCGCACGCAGGCGGTCTGTCAA
GTCTGATGTGAAATCCCCGGGCTCAACCTGGNAACTGCATTCNAAACTGGCAGGCTTGAGTCTTGNAGANGGGGGGTAGA
ATTCCAGGTGTANCGNTGAAATGCGTANAGATCTGGANGNAATACCGGTGGCNAANGCGGCCCCCTGGACAAAGACTGAC
GCTCANGTGCGAAAGCGTGGNGGAGCAAANAGGATTAGATACCCTGGTAGNCCNNCGCCNNANACGATGTCTACNTGGNA
GGNTTGTGNCCTTGAGGCGTGNCTNNCCNGNAGCTNAACGCGTTTAAGTANANCNNCCTGGGGCGAGCNACGGGCNGCNN
GGNTNAAAACNNNNNNTGNNNTTNNACGGGNGNNCCCCGCANNANCCGGCTGNNAGCATGNTGGATTNAANTTCGATNNN
NNCGCGAAGAANCCNNANNNNNGNNNNNNNANNNNNNNNNNAANNNTNNNNNANANNNNNNNNNNNNNNNGNNNNCTNNN
AGNANNGNNNCTGCATGGNNNNCNNNCNNGNTCNNGNNNNNNNNNNNNNGNNNNNNNNCCNNNANNNNNNNNNNNNTNAT
CNNNNNNNNNNNNNTNNNNNNNNNNNNNAGNNNNNNNNCNNNNNNNNNNANNTNNNAANN
>47
NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNGNNNNNCGGGTNNCCNNNNGCTGGNTGNNNTGCTGACGAGTGGCGGACGGGTGAGT
AATGTCTGGGAAACTGCCTGAAGGGGGGGGATTCCTACTGGCCAGGGTGGCTAATACCGGGTAACGTCGNNNGANCAAAG
AGGGGGACCTTCGGGCCTCTTGCCATCACATGTGCCCGGATGGGATTAGCTTGTTGGTGAGGTAACGGCTCACCAAGGCG
ACGATCCCTAGCTGGTCTGAGAGGATGACCAGCCNCACTGGAACTGAGACACGGTCCCGACTCCTACGGGAGGCANCAGT
GGGGAATATTGCTCTTGGGCGCAAGCCTGATGCAGCCATGCCGCGGGTATGAGGAAGGCCTTCGGTTTGTAAAGTACTTT
CTCCGGGGAGGAAGGNGTNGTGGTGAATAACCGCTACANTTGANNCTNCCCGCNNAANAACCACCNGNTAACTCCNTGCN
NNNNGCCGCGGTAATACGGANGGTGCAAGNGTTAATCGNANTTACTGNNTGTTGAGCGCACGNNGGCGGCCTGTCNNNTC
TNATGTGAGATCCCCGGGCTCNCCCTGNNACCTGCATTCGNNNNNTGNNANGCTNGANTCTTGNNNNGNNGNGGNAGNAA
TTCCNNGTGTNNCGNNGAAATGCNNANAGATCTGNANANANNACNGGNGNCCAANGNNGNCCCCTGNTCTCNGACTGACG
CNNGAGTGCTGAANNGTGNAGAGCGNACAGGATTANANNNCCNGNTAGNCCGNCNCCNCACACCNATGTCTACATGNGAG
GNTNNNGNNNNNTGNGGCNNNNCNNTCCNNNAGCTNANGNNGTTNAANTANATCNNNCTNNNNCNNGCNNGGGGNCANNA
NGGGNNNAAANNTNNNNATNAATNTGACGGANNNNNCNNNNNNNNCNNNNNNANCATGNGGATTNANNNTNNNTNNNNNC
NNNNNANAACCNNANNNNNNNNNNNNNNTNNNNNNNANNNTNNNNNNNTNNNNNNGNNNNCNNNNNNNNACTNNNNNNNC
NNNNNNNNCANNGNNNNNNNNNNNANGNTNNNNNTGNNNNAANNNTGNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNTN
NNNNNNTNNNNNNNTNNNNTNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNTNNNNNNNNTCNNNNNN
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Can you provide a reproducible example of this (i.e. some fasta sequence that produces more than >3 hits?) I am trying to get the same problem but I seem to get the right number of hits (under `<Hit>`)

Comment: Sure! Could you also share your fasta sequence so I could have a look?

Comment: @cnluzon Update on this: I think my problem is with my XML parsing. I'm in the process of actually figuring out what I did wrong, but I think it has something to do with my `for` loop calling `alignment.hsps` and looping around those, as opposed to my hits.


`from Bio.Blast import NCBIXML`
`with open("XML_Files/46_47.xml") as result_handle:`
   `blast_records = NCBIXML.parse(result_handle)`
    `x = 0`
   `for rec in blast_records:`
       `for alignment in rec.alignments:`
                `for hsp in alignment.hsps:`
                        `#print(rec.query)#DNA ID`

Comment: Oh I see! Well if you are looking for alignments it may be the case that you should use the parameter `alignments=3` instead of `hitlist_size` as defined here: http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/api/Bio.Blast.NCBIWWW-module.html

Comment: @Cnluzon Do you think you could quickly define alignments vs hitlist? I'm not quite seeing their difference.

Comment: I am not 100% sure because I do not see more info in the documentation, but my guess would be that more than one alignment could correspond to a single hit, and that would be the reason why you get more than the specified number of elements in your lists, because you are accessing `rec.alignments`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems that a **hit** is something different than an **alignment**. A **hit** is a sequence match in the database, whereas an **alignment** is the actual position of the nucleotides. This could happen several times for the same sequence in the database.

In the case you tried, the xml that this saves has indeed three items under `<Hit>`, but the last hit you get has **seven** `<Hsp>` records, which seem to be what you are iterating through with the loop:

```
for rec in blast_records:
    for alignment in rec.alignments:
        for hsp in alignment.hsps:
            print(rec.query) #DNA ID
```

Specifying `alignments=3` instead of hits will get you 3 alignments maximum per hit, I think. You can specify both, if you want to control number of hits and number of alignments.

Comment: Your solution solved my problem. I needed to specify both `hitlist_size = 3` as well as `alignments=1` in order to get the first three hits and the first <HSP> record in my XML file.

Comment: Glad to hear! :)